# How should I use rel="canonical" in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, seo

Google recently came out with their mobile best practices: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details

My question regards how to set the rel="canonical" links for the various pages on my mobile site, given the way pages work in Jquery Mobile.

Should I not worry about the other pages (such as locations, contacts, etc.) and only focus on having the following in my head:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="website.com" >
```

Maybe I should include all the canonical links in the head?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="website.com" >
<link rel="canonical" href="website.com/locations" >
<link rel="canonical" href="website.com/contact-us" >
```

Or should I include the canonical link in each individual jquery mobile "page"?

```
<div data-role="page" id="locations" data-theme="a">
<link rel="canonical" href="website.com/locations" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put a canonical tag in each page. (Your last option listed.)

Crawlers will hit your site without JavaScript enabled to grab these tags.

So, you need to set the canonical tags for each page individually, such that linking directly to that page: `http://localhost:8080/some/path` would set the canonical URL as such. Don't worry about it changing on each pageshow event.

#### Info below this point is not for SEO, more for fun/curiosity

If you wanted to be able to change the canonical tag on pageshow, toss this in your JS:

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function() {
    $('link[rel=canonical]').attr('href',$('base').attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: So to be clear, you're saying I should go with the last option I suggested?

Comment: Also, thanks for that little code snippet. I'll probably just use that.

Comment: No problem. My goal is to be helpful :P. If you use that code snippet alone, when the crawlers hit your pages, it won't work (due to JS being disabled when they crawl your site)

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. Just create a variable $canonical on each request and `<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $canonical; ?>"/>`. To test, either disable JS or go to each page and refresh and inspect the head.

Comment: This answer seems fine, except when you're using the multi page feature in jQuery Mobile. I don't know how Google will tell that each div with data-role="page" should be treated as a separate page, with it's own separate canonical link. Any solutions here?

Comment: Brett, you say 'Info below this point is not for SEO'. So there is no way to change canonical tag after page was loaded? Is there any other way to have canonicals on # link change?

Comment: @besimple You can change the canonical tag after the page is loaded. Web crawlers will pull the canonical url on page load. So, changing the canonical tag value after that point will not be helpful to the indexing of your site.